# How can I access a specific resource file programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

My application is in two languages: English and French.
English is stored in Global.resx file
French is stored in Global.fr.resx file

I am writing bilingual email notifications using the data from these resource files.

How can I programatically access the contents of Global.fr.resx when I am writing the french version?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SelectedCulture As String = "fr-CA"
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(SelectedCulture)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
'Code will now retrieve from the French resource file
Dim AppName as string= Resources.Strings.AppName
```